# Sending emojis with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I know that questions like this have already been asked but I have not found a clear answer that really works.

I want to **send automatically dm on social medias** but I want to **add emojis in it**. The thing is that I don't understand how do people send it because it is not allowed by the Chromedriver (it is said that only BMP is supported).

Indeed, I have found a solution to add text in an input, which is as follows :

```
JS_ADD_TEXT_TO_INPUT = """
var elm = arguments[0], txt = arguments[1];
elm.value += txt;
elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
"""
```

In my case, the place where i want to add emoji is not always an input (it can be a span or a div). Does someone have an idea about what code could help me to do that ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to add an emoji to a non-input field, you could set the `textContent` directly to it.

```py
script = """document.querySelector('%s').textContent='%s';""" % (
        css_selector,
        value,
    )
driver.execute_script(script)
```

Be sure to escape any quotes & special characters before feeding a selector in there. Eg. `import re; re.escape(css_selector)`

That will let you set any text on a web page element to anything, including emojis if you're not typing into an input field.

Comment: Thank you for your help ! By the way I have also found that you siply need to go on firefox webdriver and there send_keys works with emojis